# ActionCommand comboBoxEdited is not getting called in executeable jar file

Tags: java, swing

I am relatively new to java I have created a swing app.
I have created a JComboBox, in actionPerformed I have the following code

```
if ( (e.getSource() == combo_VEHICLE_NUMBER) &&
     (e.getActionCommand().equals("comboBoxEdited")))
{
    combo_VEHICLE_NUMBER.addItem(combo_VEHICLE_NUMBER.getSelectedItem());
    combo_VEHICLE_NUMBER.setSelectedIndex(-1);
}
```

This works well in debug, however when I create an executeable jar file the "comboboxedited" actioncommand doesn't get called. Please help me out if someone faced a similar issue.

Comment: Why are you adding an item inside an action listener? This will actually add an item every time you edit combobox.

Comment: Why would the source and the `actionCommand` be different?  How many instances of `combo_VEHICLE_NUMBER` would you actually be able to make?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Run the Jar from the command line and check for output, but first make sure that any `catch` statements will print useful information.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. It was some problem while jar creation. I deleted the jar and created it again after cleaning the project. It works fine now